# Adicionar efeito fadein nesse código jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, transição

Bom dia!
Estou usando o seguinte código para pegar o resultado de um formulário e jogá-lo na página sem precisar recarregar:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // Script
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "salvaregistro.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data )
                {
                    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = data;
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

No entando este código somente lança o texto.
Gostaria de saber se tem como aplicar o efeito fadein para o texto aparecer mais suave digamos...

Comment: Você sabia que você pode escolher uma das respostas dadas a você como a mais correta e que lhe ajudou mais? Eu vi que você não escolheu nenhuma resposta em nenhuma pergunta que você fez. Você não gostou de nada? Nenhuma lhe ajudou? Ou apenas não sabia disto? E também pode votar em tudo o que achar interessantes no *site*. Votar ajuda classificar conteúdo de qualidade. Você pode votar em todas as perguntas e respostas que achar que são úteis, não só em respostas dados em perguntas suas. Veja o [tour] para saber mais. Sugiro revisar todas as respostas e aceitar uma delas sempre que possível.

Comment: Opa, acabei de escolhee a resposta

Comment: Ótimo, não esquece de revisar todas suas perguntas e ver onde dá para aceitar algum coisa como solução final para você. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21825/guilherme?tab=questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloca um `display: none;` no elemento `#resultado` e troca isso:

```
document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = data;
```

por isso:

```
$('#resultado').html(data).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Então mano funcionou perfeitamente, o problema é que não está pegando mais a classe da div: <div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Por favor digite um Usuário!</div>

Comment: Não entendi. Essa é a div do resultado?

Comment: Sim. No caso no arquivo .php de validação eu botei o seguinte: echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Por favor digite um Usuário!</div>"; E quando o resultado aparece na oágina, ele não aparece com essa class aplicada, aparece com ela literalmente escrita... Imagme: http://puu.sh/g2bBN/307dbcc8a8.png

Comment: Ah, tem que trocar `text()` por `html()` então. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Isso! Funcionou perfeitamente xD Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Você pode aceitar esta resposta. [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 0):

Tente com algo tipo assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // Script
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "salvaregistro.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function( data ){
                    jQuery('#resultado').hide(0).html(data).fadeIn(400);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```